# Java spring post form one to many relationship

Tags: spring-mvc, post, one-to-many

I'm trying to get POST form data on controller of the object have one to many relationship. Like below code

My Notification Model

```
private long id;
@NotBlank(message = ERROR.NOT_EMPTY)
private String title;
@NotBlank(message = ERROR.NOT_EMPTY)
private String content;
// One Notification has many User
private List<NotificationUser> listNotificationUser;;

// Getter and setter method
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "notification/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String create(ModelMap model) {
    ArrayList<User> listUser = userService.getAllUsername();
    model.put("user", listUser);
    model.addAttribute("notification", new Notification());

    return "notification/add";

}
@RequestMapping(value = "notification/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "notification") Notification notification, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ....
}
```

My .jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" action="add" name="addForm" commandName="notification">
        <!-- Other input -->
        <form:select path="listNotificationUser" multiple="multiple" id="name" name="itemValue">
          <form:options />
          <form:options items="${user}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
        </form:select>
      <!-- Other input -->
      </form:form>
```

When I submit POST form to controller, the field notification.listNotificationUser always is null (other field is fine).

I was search and try some solution but it not working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem its you have a typo in your form:select. You are defining 2 options blocks, and I guess you want to define just an empty option. So should be like this

```
<form:select path="listNotificationUser" multiple="multiple" id="name" name="itemValue">
     <!-- Some value you can identify as empty option--> 
     <form:option value="0" label="--Options--"/> 
     <form:options items="${user}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seem not working, notification.listNotificationUser is an empty ArrayList :(

Comment: I just noticed a problem, your user list store objects type User but the attribute listNotificationUser stores NotificationUser, so its not going to work, you need to use same kind of objects